# Windows can't find the 64-bit JDK

Tags: cmd, java, java-7

I just installed the 64-bit version of the Java 7 JDK on my computer, but when I load up Command Prompt and call `javac` it can't find it. What's going on here?

Comment: Looks like your PATH environment variable doesn't have the JDK/bin directory referenced.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - /me facepalms. How can I patch this?

Comment: Edit your PATH environment variable and add the proper path to it. It's not hard to do it. There are lot of examples on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an error something like

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

while issuing javac in command prompt, please try the following to add Java to your system path.

1. Right-click the **My Computer** icon on your desktop and select **Properties**.
2. Click the **Advanced** tab.
3. Click the **Environment Variables** button. Under System Variables, click New.
4. Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.
5. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit. Example: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin**
6. Click OK.
7. Add **;%JAVA_HOME%** to the end of Path environment variable. The **JAVA_HOME** environment variable created in steps 4-6 is pointing to the JDK folder.
8. Click Apply Changes.
9. Now re-open the command prompt and try again.

You might need to restart windows.